# Simple node.js, connecting to server

Tags: javascript, http, node.js

I'm learning node.js and am trying to connect to the server I've created but my browser won't connect. I'm testing on a live server.

My server.js in my /public_html consists of this:

```
var http = require("http"); 

function onRequest(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");   
    response.end(); 
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server has started");
```

which I launch from the console via node server.js and I get the "Server has started" message but when I point my browser at myhost.com:8888 it won't connect., after trying for a long time I get  Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset. What am I forgetting?

Comment: wondering - is this working on localhost for you?  are you sure the URL is correct - have you tried using the IP address and port number to connect instead of using the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code should work on localhost - I tested. Are you able to access the IP address and port e.g. 23.25.125.87:8888 (instead of myhost.com:8888) - not sure if you have looked into DNS changes (or if they gone into effect if you have already done that)

Comment: The host is actually hedonsoft.com (http://74.220.215.203:8888/) Tried with just ip but same result. I don't know if this is relevant but from a cmd in Windows I tried pinging hedonsoft.com and although it resolved the ip to 74.220.215.203 it didn't get a response, timed out.

Comment: is there a firewall service there blocking traffic?

Comment: is there a firewall service there blocking traffic?  are you sure port 8888 is open for traffic?  if you only have port 80 and/or 443 open, can you try your nodejs server listening on those ports (or perhaps use another server in front e.g. nginx/varnish etc and proxy back to port 8888 for nodejs)

Comment: That was it. My host (hostmonster.com) blocks most ports and requires purchase of a dedicated ip account to use additional ports. I'll do my dev locally and when I'm ready to go live I'll look at an account upgrade. Thanks.